# GCD dispatch_apply shared read-only resource slows down execution

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, shared-memory, readonly

I am trying to speed up my iOS App by using Grand Central Dispatch's dispatch_apply method for parallel execution of multiple independent tasks.
However, these tasks share a readonly resource (a large uint8_t array), which is accessed via a readonly, nonatomic object property.
Since it is a readonly resource, no synchronized access is necessary. Nevertheless, the shared readonly array makes the execution extremely slow. It is even slower than the serial execution of all the tasks. But if I make a local copy of the array for each thread, the tasks are executed very fast.

I don't get why I have to create a copy for each thread to benefit from GCD in case of a readonly resource. Is there any automatic internal synchronization going on which slows down execution time because GCD doesn't know it is a readonly resource? Is it somehow possible to prevent the slow down without creating a local copy of the resource for each thread?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Removed the `Greatest Common Divisor` tag; that has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be seeing cache line contention between processors. You don't show how exactly you're using `dispatch_apply`, but you might try implementing a striding strategy as described in the `dispatch_apply` man page. The key to eliminating any cache line contention is to ensure that the dispatch worker threads are not trying to access elements of the shared array that occupy the same cache line.

If the array is dynamically allocated, it will start on a suitably aligned address, so you can simply choose a stride width that is a multiple of the cache line size. You can safely assume that the cache line size of your processor is some small multiple of 64 bytes, so stride widths of 128, 256, 512 or 1024 are reasonable.